# C++ - Add variables and functions to a templated class based on template argument

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, specialization

I have something like this:

```
template <typename T, int N> class Data {
    typedef Data<T, N> data;
    public:
        T y;
        data *ptr[N];
};
```

And what I would like to able to add variables and functions to the class if `N == 2`, for example:

```
template <typename T, int N> class Data {
    typedef Data<T, N> data;
    public:
        T y;
        data *ptr[N];

        /* if N == 2, add the following members to the class */
        int x;
        data *left()  { return ptr[0] };
        data *right() { return ptr[1] };
};
```

---

I know one can use inheritance or specialization, but there is problems on both of them.

Inheritance doesn't make any sense in this specific case because the variable `ptr` points to the same class, so if I use:

```
template <typename T> class Data2 : Data<T, 2> {
    typedef Data2<T> data;
    public:
        int x;
        data *left()  { return ptr[0] }; // Error (ptr has type Data<T,N>)
        data *right() { return ptr[1] }; // Error
};
```

the variable `ptr` that `Data2` inherits from `Data` would point to the class `Data` and not `Data2`, rendering the base class useless.

The problem with specialization is that I would have to copy the entire base class to the specialization, and for smaller cases this might be okay, but if I have a really complex class or if I want custom variables and functions for several values of `N`, that would be impractical.

---

I also know the existence of `std::enable_if` which I think can solve the problem for functions, but it does not so for variables.

If anyone has a solution for it or a different approach that would bypass this, please let me know.

Answer (score 4):

You can specialize your template declarations for particular values of `N`, and use another level of inheritance indirection for the common code in your base class, that doesn't depend on `N`:

```
template <typename T> class DataBase {
    public:
        T y;
};

template <typename T, int N> class Data : public DataBase {
    typedef Data<T, N> data;
    public:
        data *ptr[N];
};
```

---

Also, without really knowing what you actually want there, I'd say something like

```
typedef T DataType;
typedef T* DataTypePtr;
```

in the base class makes more sense for me.

Comment: That would not work, because if I create an instance of class `Data`, I would have access to the variable `y`, and I only want to have a variable `y` **if** `N = 2` (in the original post it was `int x` and not `T y`)

Comment: @Mehlins Please make more clear what's the purpose of  `y` and `x` in your class design. You could still resort to the [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) to inject the definition of `x` from your inherited class.

Comment: Ok, I would want my class to have both the variable `x` and the functions `left()` and `right()` if and only if `N=2`. The variables `y` and `ptr` are to be there whatever it is the value of `N`.

Answer (score 2):

> Inheritance doesn't make any sense in this specific case

It depends if it's used alone or if it's used with a mix of `friend` class declaration and *CRTP* idiom:

```
template<typename, int>
struct BaseData { };

template<typename T>
struct BaseData<T, 2> {
    int x;
    typename T::data *left() { return static_cast<T*>(this)->ptr[0]; }
    typename T::data *right() { return static_cast<T*>(this)->ptr[1]; }
};

template <typename T, int N>
class Data: public BaseData<Data, N> {
    friend class BaseData<Data, N>;
    using data = Data<T, N>;

public:
   T y;
    data *ptr[N];
};
```

Comment: Ok, I was fiddling with this for a bit and your solution also doesn't work. I understood what you meant with the CRTP, but first of all, the `typename T` in the `BaseData` declaration is not a typename but a template instead, and the declaration should be `template<template<..> .., int>`. Besides that, I concluded that it's impossible because since `Data` is a template that would require `BaseData` to be instantiated, which, by using `T::data` would require `Data` to be instantiated, creating a circular dependency. The only option would be for `Data` to not be a template, not possible here.

Comment: @Mehlins Try to show a meaningful example next time. Otherwise, it's impossible to help guessing that *data is something different*. That said, I don't think it's impossible, it would probably require a bit of extra work.

Answer (score 0):

As skypjack mentioned, it is possible with a CRTP. A "working" example coming close to your example would look like this:

```
template <typename T, int N, typename Derived >
class DataBase {
    public:
        typedef Derived data;
        T y;
        typename DataBase<T,N,Derived>::data *ptr[N];
};


template <typename T, int N>
class Data : public DataBase< T, N, Data<T,N> > {
};


template <typename T>
class Data2 : public DataBase< T, 2, Data2<T> > {
    public:
        int x;
        typename DataBase<T,2,Data2<T> >::data* left()  { return DataBase<T,2,Data2<T> >::ptr[0]; }
        typename DataBase<T,2,Data2<T> >::data* right() { return DataBase<T,2,Data2<T> >::ptr[1]; }
};

int main() {


  Data2<double> myData;

  Data<double,5> myData5;

  myData.y = 3.0;
  myData.x = 5;

  myData.left();
  myData.right();

  myData5.y = 42.0;

}
```

A CRTP of course implies that you never can directly instantiate the class DataBase directly without having a derived class. If this is not what you need, please give the broader context to understand the situation a bit better.

EDIT: I have changed the code to include a generic derived class with no extra features.

Comment: Sorry, your example also doesn't work, because I want to be able to instantiate the class `Data` with other values for `N` beyond `2`. In your example I would have to create an infinite number of classes that inherit from `DataBase`, one for every possible value of `N`.

Comment: You can add a templated derived class for the unaltered case.